# grails plugin questions

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm a new of grails plugin,
Here are my questions:

**1.** How to log plugin's service/controller 's log?

for example, my plugin has: system.TzLibService, system.UserController

how to set log4j config in mainapp config, in order to show all logs of my plugin's classes.

**2.** Is there anyway to change mainapp's Config.groovy?

i want to change grails.config.locations after install my plugin
in _install.groovy, add some ant commond? how?

**3.** inline plugin can't call _install.groovy ?

### **4. plugin's controller do not add log method?**

system.UserController is one controller of my plugin

it extends utils.AbstractController (at plugin's src/groovy)

when visit /user/listAjax (extend from AbstractController), "log.info" can't find:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: log for class:
> system.UserController Possible
> solutions: g, jq, list, r, show
> at system.UserController.propertyMissing(UserController.groovy)
>
> at ssh.AbstractController.getProperty(AbstractController.groovy)
>
> at ssh.AbstractController$_closure3.doCall(AbstractController.groovy:37)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q4 SLOVED. see https://github.com/grails/grails-core/commit/70102e891f0574f44d295d7f3732c71b69322401#diff-0